# What does "Cannot initialize return object of type FOO with an rvalue of type BAR" mean?

Tags: objective-c

I presume that 'rvalue' is just shorthand for *return value*. What does it mean to *initialize a return object*? This is my main question. The rest is context of my particular situation, but I'm really interested in the general answer.

I'm looking at someone else's code:

```
return [p_facebook.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
```

In theory this is calling:

```
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

I'm seeing: `Cannot initialize return object of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an rvalue of type 'id'`. I'm guessing that this class might be defined somewhere else and I have a path issue...

Comment: Is there a warning about "may not implement handleOpenURL:" too?

Comment: There isn't. Sadly this code generates more warnings than Xcode wants to display due to legal but not syntactically favored constructs.

Comment: I solved my compilation problem by hunting down an older .h in the header search path that was taking precedence over the one in my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, `rvalue` is not "return value" but shorthand for (roughly) "right-hand value," or an object that appears on the right hand side of an assignment or statement. I think you may find in the implementation of `-handleOpenURL:` that it returns an object of type `id` at some point, which is obviously incompatible with the declared `BOOL` return type. If you have access to the source of `-handleOpenURL:`, I'd recommend checking there for erroneous returns first.

Comment: So is anything being "initialized" here? Maybe I don't understand the word. Seems like an illegal "assignment". I'd also think that this would be a runtime exception since the signature of the method is clean. My suspicion is that there might be a duplicate of this class somewhere that returns an id. Doing some searching. The most obvious copy I can see is only returning legitimate BOOLs.

Comment: The error makes a more sense to me if you just ignore the word "initialize" -- Cannot return object of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an rvalue of type 'id' -- although now that I understand it I can see the case for the way they have it.